# Python Web-scraped text, print vertically

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

This is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

url = ("https://overwatchleague.com/en-us/schedule?stage=regular_season&week=12")

driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\\Program Files (x86)\\chromedriver.exe')

driver.get(url)


MatchScores = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//* 
[@id="__next"]/div/div/div[3]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div[13]/div/section/div[3]')[0]

Results = MatchScores.text

print('-----------------------------')

print(Results)
```

When I run it, I get something like this:

```
FRI, JUL 02
FINAL
Paris Eternal
1
-
3
San Francisco Shock
MATCH DETAILS
FRI, JUL 02
FINAL
Washington Justice
0
-
3
Atlanta Reign
MATCH DETAILS
```

This continues for the other matches. Is there a way for me to print in so that it comes out like this?

```
FRI, JUL 02 FINAL Paris Eternal 1 - 3 San Francisco Shock
FRI, JUL 02 FINAL Washington Justice 0 - 3 Atlanta Reign
```

Any help would be appreciated, it would be a bonus if it could be printed without the "MATCH DETAILS" at the back.

Answer (score 0):

You really just need to convert all newlines to spaces. This can be done with  first splitting by newlines then join with spaces.

You can remove `MATCH DETAILS` by removing the last 13 characters.

Hence it is like this:

```py
print(' '.join(Results.split('\n'))[:-13])
```

Comment: If I run this code, it only prints MATCH DETAILS, it wont print anything else

Comment: Sorry, should be `[:-13]` in the last part. Should be fixed now.

Comment: It worked partially, I changed the line a bit and added a new line of code and it works perfectly now. Thank You